# Difference between React.createClass and <Name> extends Component

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react-native

I've been through several tutorials and guides for React Native and have seen these two being used in almost the same way:

```
var anyName = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
   return (
     ...
   );
  }
});
```

and

```
class anyName extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
     ...
   )
  }
}
```

Not sure what the difference between them is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first piece of code creates new JS object in *old way* (ES5). It simply creates plain JS object and then fill it with React methods and properties using `prototypes`.

`React.createClass` method must be filled with object that implements `render` method. (You can read more about this method [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/classic/class/ReactClass.js).

The second code uses newest JS standard (ES6) *classes* and *inheritance*. In fact `Component` is `ReactComponent` and you can read more about it [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/modern/class/ReactComponent.js).

Please note that these two ways of initializing React Component will give you sightly different results. For example you cannot use `mixins` at this time with ES6 inheritance and you have to `bind` methods to parent object. You can read more about differences [here](http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/refactoring-react-components-to-es6-classes).

Comment: Great, thanks for your explanation - very helpful. So they are very similar as I thought and it seems the second method extending component is actually a more up to date way of doing it?

Comment: Yup. Right now I'm using the ES6 way in my projects.

Comment: Be aware that with class approach you cannot use mixins and have to bind context with callbacks!

Comment: You're right, I just found that out the hard way as well.